# Eclipse doesn't create blank/empty activity

Tags: java, android, eclipse, adt, eclipse-adt

I installed eclipse-inst-win64.exe(Eclipse Neon) on windows 7. But when I tried to create new android project and empty activity it doesn't close the window when i click finish button! Could any one tell me how to fix this problem and create empty activity.Thanks

Eclipse Neon version:

```
Version: Neon Release (4.6.0)
Build id: 20160613-1800
```

Steps to create android project with empty activity:

```
-File -> New -> Project and  select Android New Application
-Press Next, follow the instructions provided and keep all other entries as default till the final step default.
-click finish
```

images of the create blank activity :

http://s16.postimg.org/5tfdj7f11/eclipse.jpg 

 http://s12.postimg.org/x7myz8iot/eclipse2.jpg

Comment: Start using Android Studio. Android for Eclipse is no longer maintained.

Comment: Thanks for replies. @Daniel Nugent . I tried that too the last step when i click finish the window never closes! I deleted the project and created new one and still the last window never closes! Is there a way to uninstall eclipse and reinstall ? or is there any other fix for this issue ?

Comment: @user1788736 follow Enzokie's advice and switch to Android Studio. Anyone who tells you otherwise is leading you astray.

Comment: @Karakuri i already have sdk tools installed if i install android studio do i need to reinstall sdk as well? Is there a way to install android studio without sdk and point to path of sdk folder in visual studio later without facing any issue ? I already installed cordova so i don't want my cordova cli stop working if i install android studio!

Comment: @user1788736 On https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html, scroll to the bottom and you can download a package with no Android SDK.

Comment: How i can add the sdk folder path to android studio later?

Comment: @user1788736 It should ask you after install, or there should be something in the settings where you set the path.